# elasticsearch mapping dynamic template

Tags: elasticsearch

What is wrong with my mapping? I receive:

```
{"error":"ClassCastException[java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List]","status":500}
```

I use ElasticSearch 1.1.1 on ubuntu server.
If I delete the dynamic templates it works

```
$this->mapping = [
        "dynamic_templates" => [
            'all_fields' => [
                'match' => "*",
                'match_mapping_type' => 'string',
                'mapping' => [
                    'index' => 'not_analyzed',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'properties' => [
            'state' => [
                'type' => 'boolean',
            ],
       ...
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping should look like this:

```
"dynamic_templates" => [
    ['all_fields' => [
        'match' => "*",
        'match_mapping_type' => 'string',
        'mapping' => [
            'index' => 'not_analyzed',
            ],
    ]],
],
```

Note the field definition should be an associative array inside a scalar array.